# Parameter to filter in the where clause SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that filters the Items based on whether its an Type I (Item) or A (Accessories). Currently this is multi select parameter where I have specified the values. But I would like to change this to a single select-able value with the following values:

- All- Items and Accessories
- I - Items
- A - Accessories
- E - Items exclude Category A and Products D

Is it possible to have case condition statements within the where clause like the following:

```
WHERE 
(CASE WHEN @Pram1 IN ('A') THEN ('I,'A')
      WHEN @Pram1 IN ('I') THEN ('I')
      WHEN @Pram1 IN ('E') THEN ('I')
 ELSE 
 -1 END)
```

THEN based on this I will have the conditions for the Categories. 
IF its 'A' then it will include all categories. IF 'E' then all from the category parameter which is also a multi select but not include Category A.

Comment: Can you supply sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just have a `case` statement by itself as listed in OP.  You can however apply a SQL filter conditionally by using a pattern such as this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM yourProductsTable p
WHERE 
--Apply the "type" filters
(
    (
        @TypeParam = 'All' --then include both Items and Accessories
        AND p.ProductType in ('I','A')
    )
    OR 
    (
        @TypeParam = 'A' --Accessories only
        AND p.ProductType = 'A'
    )
    OR
    (
        @TypeParam = 'I' --Items only
        AND p.ProductType = 'I'
    )
    OR
    (
        @TypeParam = 'E' --Items only, but Exclude Category A and Product D
        AND p.ProductType = 'I'
        AND p.Category <> 'A'
        AND p.Product <> 'D'
    )
)
--Apply Other filters: i.e. category
AND p.Category in (@SSRSCategoryMultiSelectParam)
```

Comment: Hey....basically there are Items in the category and I want to filter Items in the OR condition to include some Items from a Subcategory. So for example when @TypePram='E', I want it to not include items in a particular subcategory minus two items. I tried this filter but then the results came in empty :S. Can you please help!!

Comment: The answer I gave is a general pattern that can be applied based on what could be inferred from your question. If you want a specific answer then please update your question and add sample data and expected results for each scenario.